# How to convert docx (bytes stream) to pdf (bytes stream) with win32com.client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, win32com

I use `win32com.client` to convert DocX to PDF. I get DocX as a bytes stream and want not to save but get pdf as a bytes stream for further processing:

```
def convert_docx_to_pdf(docx_bytes_stream):
    pdf_bytes_stream = bytes

    temporary_file_name = "temporary.docx"

    with open(temporary_file_name, 'wb') as out:
        out.write(docx_bytes_stream.getbuffer())

    absolute_path = (os.path.abspath(temporary_file_name))
    pure_path = re.sub(temporary_file_name + "$", "", absolute_path)
    print(pure_path)

    word_app = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Word.Application")
    word_doc = word_app.Documents.Open(absolute_path)

    word_doc.SaveAs(pure_path + "temporary.pdf", 17)

    os.remove(absolute_path)
    
    with open (pure_path + "temporary.pdf", "rb") as f:
        pdf_bytes_stream = f.read()

    os.remove(pure_path + "temporary.pdf")

    return pdf_bytes_stream
```

In the documentation, I could find that only the file name string is allowed as an argument to open the file.docx `(word_app.Documents.Open("file.docx"))` and it is only possible to save it as file.pdf `(word_doc.SaveAs("file.pdf", 17))`. So I have a very ugly and complex solution I read my bytes stream, save it as file.docx, open it and save it as file.pdf, and then read pdf and make a byte stream from it.

Is there no possibility of reading the bytes stream (BytesIO), converting it to PDF, and getting the result as bytes stream with `win32com.client` or is it possible to rewrite this code to avoid saving and opening twice?

Comment: if function can get only filename (but not `file-like` object) then you can't use `BytesIO` and you have to save it in file and later read this file. Of course you may try to rewrite it on your own - but it may run directly some C/C++ library and then it can't be done. But all this need to check source code - and this can be long and hard work.

Comment: You can write to standard output, if you pass the number 1 to the open function instead of a filename.